# Can you pass an UI object created in a BackgroundWorker thread to the main thread?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf window with a RichTextBox control on it. When I open a text file, I parse the contents and create Paragraph objects and then insert those in the RTB document. Everything worked fine. However, while refactoring the app, I decided to try to move that routine to a BackgroundWorker. But when a I try to assign the resulting FlowDocument from the background process back to the RTB in the main thread, I get an error: the the process cannot access the object because it belongs to another thread.
I am accessing the FlowDocument from the Worker RunWorkerCompleted method. Shouldn't I be able to assing it to the RTB from there?

I tried setting the e.Result to a FlowDocument created in the DoWork method and then assigning it to the RTB in the RunWorkerCompleted method. 
I also tried passing a FlowDocument created in the main thread to the DoWork method, in case it was the case that I was getting an error because the FlowDocument was being created in the background thread.

This was my first try:

```cs
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string[] paragraphs = (string[])e.Argument;

    FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument();

    foreach (string paragraph in paragraphs)
    {
        // Create paragraph object.
        Paragraph paragraphContent = new Paragraph(new Run(paragraph));
        // Check maximum length.
        paragraphContent.Background = CheckParagraphLength(paragraphContent);
        //Add paragraph to document.
        document.Blocks.Add(paragraphContent);
    }

    e.Result = document;
}
```

The I tried creating an object to pass to the DoWork method:

```cs
public class DocInfo
{
    public string[] paragraphs {get; set;}
    public FlowDocument document {get; set;}
}
```

...and passed that objecto to the method:

```cs
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DocInfo doc = (DocInfo)e.Argument;

    foreach (string paragraph in doc.paragraphs)
    {
        // Create paragraph object.
        Paragraph paragraphContent = new Paragraph(new Run(paragraph));
        // Check maximum length.
        paragraphContent.Background = CheckParagraphLength(paragraphContent);
        // Add paragraph to document.
        doc.document.Blocks.Add(paragraphContent);
    }

    e.Result = doc;
}
```

In the first, the RunWorkerCompleted method was:

```cs
private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Editor.Document = (FlowDocument)e.Result;
}
```

In the second:

```cs
private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Editor.Document = ((FlowDocument)e.Result).document;
}
```

In both cases the result was an error accessing the object in the RunWorkerCompleted method.

Comment: Generally speaking, you're not allowed to access controls from any thread other than the UI thread.  You could try an Invoke.

Comment: Consider to google "flowdocument thread-safety".  You'll find a good existing answer on SO that matches your problem exactly.  I'm fairly sure that XamlWriter.Save() is the best workaround.

Comment: "result was an error" - what error? Always post full error messages and stack trace, as text.

Comment: How large is `paragraphs.Length`? In other words, does it really pay to do this in the background?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a `FlowDocumnet` in any other thread than an UI thread. `FlowDocument` derives from `DispatcherObject`.

> Only the thread that the `Dispatcher` was created on may access the
>   `DispatcherObject` directly. To access a `DispatcherObject` from a thread
>   other than the thread the `DispatcherObject` was created on, call `Invoke`
>   or `BeginInvoke` on the `Dispatcher` the `DispatcherObject` is associated
>   with...
>
> Objects that derive from `DispatcherObject` have thread affinity.

So any `DispatcherObject` that will be used on the UI thread must be created on this very thread, which is because of the STA threading model WPF is build on. The only exception is an object that derives from `Freezable`. A `Freezable` can be created on any thread and once frozen passed across threads, since freezing will cause the `Freezable` to unhook from the dispatcher system. The thread affinity is then lifted and therefore the Dispatcher notification mechanism won't be active anymore. That's why `Freezable` types improve performance when in the frozen state. So to create a `FlowDocument` in another thread, this thread has to be a UI thread ([Running WPF Application with Multiple UI Threads](https://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/)). But because of its thread affinity you can only use it on this thread and cannot pass it back to the other UI thread. To solve your problem without running a second `Window` you would have to follow Hans Passant's suggestion to serialize the `FlowDocument` into a `XDocument` and then modify it in.
In case you decide to create the document without a background thread you could defer creation using the `Dispatcher` and play around with the priority (e.g. `DispatcherPriority.Background` or `DispatcherPriority.Idle)` if the procedure slows down the UI.

Comment: How exactly would multiple UI threads solve this problem?  You would have to redesign the UI at least.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes of course. I edited the answer to make it more clear. Thank you.